# Hiding command prompt when using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: tkinter, pyinstaller, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to create an executable that will run without showing the command prompt. I'm using `pyinstaller` to create the executable and the `--noconsole` option to hide the command prompt, but the program uses `wkhtmltopdf` which still causes a command prompt to open.

The only option I found to use with `wkhtmltopdf` is `-quiet`, which stops it from outputting anything, but this still causes a command prompt to open, it's just blank.

I don't know if there's an option I'm missing that can be used with `wkhtmltopdf` or if there's some other workaround.

```
import pdfkit

path_to_wkhtmltopdf = 'S:\!Data Processing\Resources\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'

config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_to_wkhtmltopdf)
pdfkit.from_file(os.path.join(folder,'temp_output.html'),os.path.join(folder, raw_file_name + ' (RAW PDF).pdf'),options={
        'margin-left': margin,
        'margin-right': '0.3in',
        'margin-top': '0.3in',
        'margin-bottom': '0.3in',
        'quiet': '', 
    },configuration=config)
```

Comment: How are you interfacing with wkhtmltopdf? If you use `subprocess` or the python wrapper the command prompt will never be invoked. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I'm using the python wrapper pdfkit

Comment: Ok, in that case your problem is not related to wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: But when the command prompt pops up, it shows in the title that it's running wkhtmltopdf.exe? Does pdfkit not call wkhtmltopdf through the command line?

Comment: No, it uses subprocess, which never invokes the terminal emulator. I've never used wkhtmltopdf.exe but I find it hard to believe that it would launch the terminal emulator either, that would be extremely unusual for a CLI program. I'm guessing this is a pyinstaller problem. Do you have this issue if you run the .pyw file instead of the .exe?

Comment: Yeah, it still pops up when I run the .pyw file. I edited the post with all of the code related to the pdfkit/wkhtmltopdf portion. It's not much, so I'm really not sure what's happening if pdfkit doesn't call the terminal itself.

Comment: I'm faced to the same issue, Did you find a way to solve it ? Thanks

Comment: @Omnia69 No I didn't